# Remove Controls from JS Video

Tags: autoplay

I'm looking to remove the controls from a JS player that I have embedded on a site. The idea is to have the video autoplay with no controls.. Here is my code:

```
<video id="Splash1" class="video-js vjs-default-skin"
   controls="off" autoplay preload="auto" width="1280" height=""
="http://video-js.zencoder.com/oceans-clip.png"
  data-setup='{"example_option":true}'>
 <source src="movie/Splash1.mp4" type='video/mp4' />
 <source src="movie/Splash1.webm" type='video/webm' />
 <source src="movie/Splash1.ogv" type='video/ogg' />
</video>
```

I was following the instructions and I removed just controls - but then the autoplay and video does not work. However, if I put back in controls the autoplay works but I have the controller playing along the bottom.

Any tips on how to get rid of the controller? Thanks so much in advance!